# Using the Script Module in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to run this command:

```
setarch $(uname -m) --uname-2.6 /opt/files/IBM/ITM/install.sh -q -h /opt/files/IBM/ITM/Install -p /opt/files/silent_install.txt
```

in Ansible using the script module but I'm not sure how to incorporate the extra args.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't run an executable using `script` module, but using a [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/command_module.html) or [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module.

Secondly, you should utilise [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) for that. The architecture (the result of `uname -m`) is stored in the `ansible_facts.architecture` fact:

```
command: setarch {{ ansible_facts.architecture }} --uname-2.6 /opt/files/IBM/ITM/install.sh -q -h /opt/files/IBM/ITM/Install -p /opt/files/silent_install.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the examples here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/script_module.html); just type them in.

```
# Example from Ansible Playbooks
- script: /some/local/script.sh --some-arguments 1234
```

...but I recommend using `copy` or `template` with `command` or `shell` as [techraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947502/techraf) suggests.